# "There are no commands defined in the cron namespace" even though I don't have any crons running

Tags: magento2, cron, magento2.3.1

I have the Magento_Cron module disabled, so as far as I know, no cron jobs should be running in my environment.

Every minute or so, the text...

```
There are no commands defined in the "cron" namespace. 

Did you mean this? 
   setup:cron
```

...gets appended to the file `var/log/magento.cron.log` (without me doing anything).

The posts that I've found about this issue mostly say that it's due to a missing `/etc/module.xml` file, but those posts seem to reference this error as a response to running some command line command.  Since in my case the error gets logged without me doing anything, I'm at a loss of how to figure out what's causing it.  Additionally, since the error is happening automatically in a log file, I don't know how to turn on any additional logging.